# Sequelize raw findAll returns unwanted ID column

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

I'm doing a SELECT query with INNER JOINS using Sequelize as the following example:

```
let result=await model.findAll({
  attributes:[['att1', 'alias1'], ['att2', 'alias2']],
  include:[{
    model:model1,
    attributes:[['att3', 'alias3']],
    include:[{
      model:model2,
      attributes:[['att4', 'alias4']]
    }] 
  }],
  limit:50,
  raw:true
})
```

I want to get an array of objects with the following format:

```
{
  alias1:value1,
  alias2:value2,
  alias3:value3,
  alias4:value4
}
```

But instead I get:

```
{
  alias1:value1,
  alias2:value2,
  model1.alias3:value3,
  model1.model2.id:rowId,
  model1.model2.alias4:value4
}
```

I'd like to know if there is a way of removing the "model." part of the property name and also if someone could explain me why Sequelize is returning the 'rowId' if I didn't include it on the attributes array and how to avoid it, So I don't have to iterate the array to get the format I want.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of research I've found the correct way to implement Vivek Doshi's idea of define my `attributes` only in the root level. To achieve that you need to use the `Sequelize.col()` function and pass the alias Sequelize is creating for the table as parameters which is usually something like `table1->table2.attribute`. So the working version of my example would be:

```
let result= await model.findAll({
  attributes:[
    ['att1', 'alias1'], ['att2', 'alias2'], [Sequelize.col('table1.att3'),
    'alias3'], [Sequelize.col('table1->table2.att4'), 'alias4']],
  include:[{
    model:model1,
    attributes:[],
    include:[{
     model:model2,
     attributes:[]
    }]
  }]
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with the `attribute` at the root level only :

```
await model.findAll({
  attributes:[['att1', 'alias1'], ['att2', 'alias2'] , ['model1.att3', 'alias3'] , ['model1.model2.att4', 'alias4']],
  // OR
  // attributes:[['att1', 'alias1'], ['att2', 'alias2'] , ['$table1.att3$', 'alias3'] , ['$table1.table2.att4$', 'alias4']],
  include:[{
    model:model1
    include:[{
      model:model2
    }] 
  }],
  limit:50,
  raw:true
})
```

Comment: This is a good idea, but didn't work with that syntax. I've posted an answer with the syntax that actually worked. Thank you for your time :)